# JMX: Standard ability to access file system where JVM is running

Tags: java, jmx

Is there a "standard" MBEAN of JMX that can allow me to read files and perhaps even run shell commands on the OS that is running the JVM?

I know I can write my own MBean, but I am working on a software that has to connect to different java processes (some are not under ny control) and unify some data from their file systems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe such an MXBean would present a large security hole so if there were such a means I am sure they would block/fix it ASAP.

If you want remote execution in a secure way I suggest you use SSH.

Answer (score 0):

If you can read files and run shell commands through a remote MBeanServer on java processes not under your control, they soon will be :)

You could take a look at [GMX](https://github.com/nickman/GroovyMX). 
Full Disclosure: This is my project.

GMX will remotely install an MBean on the remote MBeanServer and you can then submit groovy scripts to it for execution. I have not tried it, (I will) but I assume you will be able to issue OS commands as well.

(There's some additional info [here](http://seeallhearall.blogspot.com/2012_01_01_archive.html)).

Comment: Does your project use standard MBeans to do this?

Comment: They're not MBeans present in a standard distribution, but they are "compliant" MBeans, if I understand your question correctly. A local Groovy client connects to a remote MBeanServer using standard JMX remoting and installs the proprietary MBeans which are then invoked upon from the client. When it's done, the MBeans are removed.